# Android: Logout from app at fixed time daily

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I need to set an alarm in my app for a fixed time, where user will get a notification(alert dialog)  to logout from app & login again. I am trying using alarm manager. Below is the code, I tried but it isn't giving any notification.

Set Alarm in Activity:

```
loginAlarm = new LoginAlarmReceiver();
loginAlarm.setAlarm(NewDashboardActivity.this);
```

LoginAlarmReceiver

```
public class LoginAlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    private AlarmManager alarmMgr;

    private PendingIntent alarmIntent;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        context,
                        0,
                        notificationIntent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );


        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setContentTitle("Login")
                .setContentText("Please logout/login again")
                //.setTicker("New Message Alert!")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.*****)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                ;
        notification.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(001, notification.build());
        Utils.alertDialogShow(context,context.getString(R.string.login_message));
    }

    // BEGIN_INCLUDE(set_alarm)

    public void setAlarm(Context context) {
        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginAlarmReceiver.class);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        //calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        // Set the alarm's trigger time to 8:30 a.m.
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 10);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);

    }
    // END_INCLUDE(set_alarm)


    // BEGIN_INCLUDE(cancel_alarm)
    public void cancelAlarm(Context context) {
            if (alarmMgr!= null) {
            alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent);
        }
    }
    // END_INCLUDE(cancel_alarm)
}
```

I tried putting break point at `"OnReceive"` but that never gets called at set time. It was 9:10 am for above code.

In the manifest file the alarm receiver is defined as below:

```
 <receiver android:name=".broadcast.LoginAlarmReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK">
    </uses-permission>
```

I checked the app settings on device and notifications are enabled for the app. Please advise what I am missing.

Comment: If have installed app and not opened it yet, it will not receive broadcast. secondly it may be due to DOZE mode also

Comment: App is active and I am waiting for notification. Lemme check for DOZE mode too. Thanks.